# How to extract features from a layer of the pretrained ResNet model Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, resnet

I trained a model with Resnet3D and I want to extract the neurons of a layer. I plan to use them with the SVM classifier. How can I extract these weights and put them to the numpy array?

Load the weights by keras

```py
model = Resnet3DBuilder.build_resnet_18((128, 96, 96, 3), nClass[0])
model.load_weights('drive/app/models/3d_resnet_modelq.hdf5')
```

extract a layer

```py
dns = model.layers[-1].output
```

now what should i do?

Comment: can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi i just tried what i wrote above in code and searched for my question and i couldn't find any answer

Comment: but have you first considered doing keras tutorials before diving straight in (or at least reading some documentation)? If you can't even start coding some lines (or look in the docs) to answer your problem you may need to start with simpler things.

Comment: Also it is unclear whether you want the weights of the last layers or if you want to use the model as a feature extractor. Can you clarify this point?

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi as i said before i trained the model in order to extract the weights of the last layer for using at the SVM.

Comment: ok so you are using the wrong terminology. Usually weights refer to the network parameters, whereas what you want to do is use the output of the last layer in an SVM.

Comment: Dear @ZaccharieRamzi, as i read a paper, they mentioned that they used the dense layer of VGG with 4096 neurons in order to add them to thier dataset for classifying with SVM. So i want to try it with my dataset

Comment: Yes I understand, and the answer of [Daniele Grattarola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56210308/4332585) is doing exactly that with any model.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi what is your idea about model.layers[-1].get_weights()? this code give me and array with shape of (512,3)

Comment: Like I said I think you are confused between the layer's weights and the layer's output. The weights are the parameters of the network whereas the output of the layer is exactly the features you are trying to extract.

Comment: Oh ok I tried it again thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to visualise the features, in pure Keras you can define a `Model` with the desired layer as output:

```
from keras.models import Model

model_cut = Model(inputs=model.inputs, output=model.layers[-1].output)
features = model_cut.predict(x)  # Assuming you have your images in x
```

Note that in order for this to work, `model` must have been compiled at least once.

Comment: thank you but i want the weights of the last layer for using to the svm calssifier

Comment: I really suggest you to read up on neural networks before going further. What you are looking for are clearly the **features** produced by the last layer, not its weights.

Comment: If it solved your problem, can you please accept the answer so it doesn't show up as unanswered to other users?

Comment: @DanieleGrattarola how to modify this to get the features and the prediction both without recomputing all till -1 layer again